# scala: if condition never evaluated

Tags: scala, if-statement

I have to write a function to find if the parenthesises are balanced in a string.
The problem is that in line 1, the if condition is always skipped.

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def butil(chars: List[Char], l: Int, r: Int): Boolean ={
    if (chars.isEmpty) l==r
    val c = chars.head
    val ret = c match {
      case '(' => butil(chars.tail, l+1, r)
      case ')' => if(l<=r) false else butil(chars.tail, l, r+1)
      case _ => butil(chars.tail, l, r)
    }
    ret
  }
  butil(chars, 0, 0)
}
```

Even the IntelliJ idea shows it in a faded text(meaning that it is never evaluated).

[image]

Comment: According to IntelliJ the faded text means `Unused expression without side effects` which is telling you that it **is** evaluated but the answer is thrown away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faded code is evaluated, it is just ignored because the `if` does nothing with it. You need to move the rest of the code into the `else` part of the first `if` and remove the spurious recursive call at the end:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {
  def butil(chars: List[Char], l: Int, r: Int): Boolean = {
    if (chars.isEmpty) {
      l==r
    } else {
      println(chars.toString())
      val c = chars.head
      c match {
        case '(' => butil(chars.tail, l+1, r)
        case ')' => if(l<=r) false else butil(chars.tail, l, r+1)       
        case _ => butil(chars.tail, l, r)
      }
    }
  }
  butil(chars, 0, 0)
}
```

A cleaner way to do with is to use `match` to test and extract head/tail at the same time:

```
def balance(chars: String): Boolean = {
  def butil(chars: List[Char], l: Int, r: Int): Boolean =
    chars match {
      case Nil         => l == r
      case '(' :: tail => butil(tail, l + 1, r)
      case ')' :: tail => if (l <= r) false else butil(tail, l, r + 1)
      case _ :: tail   => butil(tail, l, r)
    }

  butil(chars.toList, 0, 0)
}
```

I've also changed the input type to `String` as that seems more natural.

Comment: I know that the first if condition is not evaluated because I get ```class java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list``` runtime error.

Comment: As I said, the `if` condition **is** executed and the `l==r` **is** evaluated. The problem is that that the result is discarded. It does not change the flow of execution, so `chars.head` is always evaluated. That is why you get the exception. Have a closer look at my answer to see why the changes I made fix the problem.